# SQL SQL query ssrs server

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have table with columns as shown below:

```
jobnum jobname description oncost
1        abc    xxxx       cost1
1        abc    xxxx       cost2
```

How can I get result in one line like below:

```
jobnum jobname description oncost
1        abc    xxxx       cost1,Cost2
```

Comment: What's the specific database?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the specific database, but you'll need to group the rows, and aggregate the last column. The query bellow **should** work on most current databases:

```
select jobnum, jobname, description, listagg(oncost,',')
  from my_table
  group by jobnum, jobname, description
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017 you can use `string_agg()` and `GROUP BY` all columns other than `oncost`.

```
SELECT t1.jobnum,
       t1.jobname,
       t1.description,
       string_agg(t1.oncost,
                  ',') oncost
       FROM elbat t1
       GROUP BY t1.jobnum,
                t1.jobname,
                t1.description;
```

For lower versions using a subquery `FOR XML` as a substritute for `string_agg()` is the typical solution to such kind of problems.

```
SELECT t1.jobnum,
       t1.jobname,
       t1.description,
       stuff((SELECT ',' + t2.oncost
                     FROM elbat t2
                     WHERE t2.jobnum = t1.jobnum
                           AND t2.jobname = t1.jobname
                           AND t2.description = t1.description
                           FOR XML PATH('')),
             1,
             1,
             '') oncost
       FROM elbat t1
       GROUP BY t1.jobnum,
                t1.jobname,
                t1.description;
```